# openssl: how can generate root certificate from .pfx file?

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, azure-aks, root-certificate

I have been provided a `.pfx` file. I would like to know how can i generate a root CA from that file please ?

My use case is:

i deployed Moon2 (test tool) on my aks cluster. Its GUI is accessible using **HTTPS** ( I created a  secret having `tls.key` and `tls.crt` that are generated from that `.pfx` file ) and everything works fine. However i get an error when i am requesting the websocket provided by this tool (ie: Moon2) saying : `browserType.connect: unable to verify the first certificate`

That is why i guess i have to run `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=root-ca.pem npm test`. But i don't know how to generate root certificate (ie: `root-ca.pem`) from .pfx file.

Any help would be appriciated !

Comment: No PFX file needed.  Access your web GUI (over HTTPS) in a browser.  View the certificate for the site.  Goto the **Details** tab.  Select the issuer CA cert.  Press the **Export...** button.  Save the `.crt` file.  Repeat these steps for any other Intermediate CA cert(s) and the Root CA cert in your cert chain.  Open your `root-ca.pem` file in a text editor.  Import the contents of each `.crt` file saved in the previous steps into your `root-ca.pem` file.  Save the `root-ca.pem` file.  Retry Moon2.